# Wrong Y axis labels order in ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

So I have this scatter plot, I want to compare CO2 emissions and this is my problem, in Y axis the labels are in wrong order, and even the plot it's wrong because it looks like this:

[image]

This is the script:

```
ggplot(data = emisiones_data) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Año, y = Emisiones , color=Región),
           size=1.65) +
scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1965,2020, 5)) +
ggtitle("Emisiones de Dióxido de Carbono",
        subtitle = "Millones de toneladas (1965-2019)") +
xlab("")+
ylab("Millones de toneladas")+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
      plot.title = element_text(color="#993333", size=15, face="bold.italic"),
      axis.title.y = element_text( size=12, face="bold"))
```

This is how it looks the df:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxYGW.png)

What can I do?

Comment: Looks like your `Emisiones` column contains commas, so it was read as type character instead of type numeric. You can either replace the commas with periods and convert to numeric, or set an option (depending on what function is used) when you read the data into R. See what `str(emisiones_data)` says for column types.

Comment: wooooow thank you so much!! It works perfectly